# MySQL error with union

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with the following sql query

```
select itemname from Item where itemid 
in

((select ItemID
 FROM Delivery NATURAL JOIN Supplier
 WHERE SupplierName = 'Nepalese Corp.')

 union

 (select ItemID
 FROM Sale NATURAL JOIN Department
 WHERE DepartmentName = 'Navigation'))
```

I have seen another post on this site that recommends removing the inner parentheses on the two union sets and giving the first union set an alias. I tried it, and MYSQL shows an x at the line shown below, however, the query runs fine. My question is what happened?

```
select itemname from Item where itemid 
in

(select ItemID as id
 FROM Delivery NATURAL JOIN Supplier
 WHERE SupplierName = 'Nepalese Corp.'

 union

 select ItemID .          //shows an x at this line
 FROM Sale NATURAL JOIN Department
 WHERE DepartmentName = 'Navigation')
```

Comment: What does "shows an x" mean?

Comment: What is the error you have ? Maybe share us a http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Also I would try replacing the line 
`select ItemID as id` by `select ItemID as itemid`

Comment: the query works but mysql shows a cross next to that line

Comment: @johnson Did you remove the alias and now you get the results you were expecting?

Comment: I get the results with or without the alias, but the cross is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select itemname from Item 
where itemid in
(
    select ItemID 
    FROM Delivery 
    NATURAL JOIN Supplier WHERE SupplierName = 'Nepalese Corp.'
    union
    select ItemID
    FROM Sale 
    NATURAL JOIN Department WHERE DepartmentName = 'Navigation'
 )
```

You can try above code.

Simply remove unnecessary brackets will resolve you issue.

Comment: That's the same thing as he has with his second example where he explains that he gets an 'x' for his results. How is this supposed to help?

Comment: this works too, without using the alias. I thought you had to use the alias for it to work.

Comment: i removed the alias but the cross is still there, I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You can try join the inner result to main table

```
 select itemname from Item as t1 join
    (select distinct ItemID
     FROM Delivery NATURAL JOIN Supplier
     WHERE SupplierName = 'Nepalese Corp.'
    union
    select distinct ItemID
     FROM Sale NATURAL JOIN Department
     WHERE DepartmentName = 'Navigation') as t2 on t1.ItemID=t2.ItemID
```